# How to limit code changes when introducing state?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a senior C/C++/Java/Assembler programmer and I have been always fascinated by the pure functional programming paradigm. From time to time, I try to implement something useful with it, e.g., a small tool, but often I quickly reach a point where I realize that I (and my tool, too) would be much faster in a non-pure language. It's probably because I have much more experience with imperative programming languages with thousands of idoms, patterns and typical solution approaches in my head.

Here is one of those situations. I have encountered it several times and I hope you guys can help me.

Let's assume I write a tool to simulate communication networks. One important task is the generation of network packets. The generation is quite complex, consisting of dozens of functions and configuration parameters, but at the end there is one master function and because I find it useful I always write down the signature:

```
generatePackets :: Configuration -> [Packet]
```

However, after a while I notice that it would be great if the packet generation would have some kind of random behavior deep down in one of the many sub-functions of the generation process. Since I need a random number generator for that (and I also need it at some other places in the code), this means to manually change dozens of signatures to something like

```
f :: Configuration -> RNGState [Packet]
```

with

```
type RNGState = State StdGen
```

I understand the "mathematical" necessity (no states) behind this. My question is on a higher (?) level: How would an experienced Haskell programmer have approached this situation? What kind of design pattern or work flow would have avoided the extra work later?

I have never worked with an experienced Haskell programmer. Maybe you will tell me that you never write signatures because you have to change them too often afterwards, or that you give all your functions a state monad, "just in case" :)

Comment: I don't think there is any way to avoid this... and this *is good*. Changing something from being pure to impure **is** a big deal, and having the code silently compile with such a change means that you have given up type safety almost completely...

Comment: How about adding a random seed into the configuration?

Comment: I wonder if this question might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com, being as it is a question about software development practices.

Comment: @chepner when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 9):

One approach that I've been fairly successful with is using a monad transformer stack. This lets you both add new effects when needed and also track the effects required by particular functions.

Here's a really simple example.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader

data Config = Config { v1 :: Int, v2 :: Int }

-- the type of the entire program describes all the effects that it can do
type Program = StateT Int (ReaderT Config IO) ()

runProgram program config startState = 
  runReaderT (runStateT program startState) config

-- doesn't use configuration values. doesn't do IO    
step1 :: MonadState Int m => m ()
step1 = get >>= \x -> put (x+1)

-- can use configuration and change state, but can't do IO
step2 :: (MonadReader Config m, MonadState Int m) => m ()
step2 = do
  x <- asks v1
  y <- get
  put (x+y)

-- can use configuration and do IO, but won't touch our internal state
step3 :: (MonadReader Config m, MonadIO m) => m ()
step3 = do
  x <- asks v2
  liftIO $ putStrLn ("the value of v2 is " ++ show x)

program :: Program
program = step1 >> step2 >> step3

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let config = Config { v1 = 42, v2 = 123 }
      startState = 17
  result <- runProgram program config startState
  return ()
```

Now if we want to add another effect:

```
step4 :: MonadWriter String m => m()
step4 = tell "done!"

program :: Program
program = step1 >> step2 >> step3 >> step4
```

Just adjust `Program` and `runProgram`

```
type Program = StateT Int (ReaderT Config (WriterT String IO)) ()

runProgram program config startState =
    runWriterT $ runReaderT (runStateT program startState) config
```

To summarize, this approach lets us decompose a program in a way that tracks effects but also allows adding new effects as needed without a huge amount of refactoring.

## edit:

It's come to my attention that I didn't answer the question about what to do for code that's already written. In many cases, it's not too difficult to change pure code into this style:

```
computation :: Double -> Double -> Double
computation x y = x + y
```

becomes

```
computation :: Monad m => Double -> Double -> m Double
computation x y = return (x + y)
```

This function will now work for any monad, but doesn't have access to any extra effects. Specifically, if we add another monad transformer to `Program`, then `computation` will still work.

Comment: This code presumes the type to modify is already a monad stack; it seems there is still a lot of refactoring to do to apply something like  `StateT StdGen` to `[Packet]`.

Comment: This is a nice snippet of code but I don't believe this answers the question at all. I.e., what should he/she do if a large amount of his code is already written differently? The answer can't be "always just start with a monad stack"

Comment: @naomik: yes, that's what I meant (half-jokingly) with "give all your functions a state monad, just in case" and I was wondering how the "real FP-guys" handle this problem. If my Haskell program has state everywhere, the difference to an impure language becomes just a question of syntax.

Comment: @RmS even if your program has state everywhere, at every point you statically know exactly what the state is. That's a significant difference to most stateful languages.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: right, but my question was more about workflow, patterns and coding style: Do I have to write my program with (at the beginning empty) state constructs (monads or whaterver you prefer) for all functions *just in case* ("Hey, maybe I will need state later and then I have to refactor everything")? Is that how the "real guys" (you, user2297560, etc.) work when they start a big project?

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Just another comment about "statically knowing the state". When I added RNGState to my program, I had to do it for every function in the path from the head function down to the function F which needed the RNG. What happens if, in a few years, I decide to change F so that it does not need the RNG anymore? Just a quick small change in F...But wait, what about all the other functions in the path? Refactor them again? Do I still remember why I put RNGState everywhere? Yes, the compiler knows, but do I? My question is about daily coding habits and work flow to make life easier.

Comment: Fair point. If you already have a bunch of code, this technique requires some amount of refactoring. I usually assume for non-trivial projects that the 'backbone' of the application will need effects (IO at the very least) so I'll start with `type Program = IO ()` and add effects as necessary.